# Show field label of a textfield?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I want to know the field label for a text field. Here's what i got so far:

```
var ok = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[itemId=fieldID]')[0];
//how to get the field label of that textfield????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the `getFieldLabel()` method as documented in [sencha docs](https://bt.associatesys.local/documentation/extjs5/ext-docs-5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-getFieldLabel)

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/r8j)

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myField')[0].getFieldLabel()`

Answer (score 1):

```
                                             {
                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Locater',
                                                width: 200,
                                                id:'txtid',
                                                labelWidth: 60,
                                                padding: '0 0 0 5',
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'button',
                                                handler: function () {
                                                    var f1 = Ext.getCmp('txtid').getFieldLabel();
                                              alert(f1);
                                                }
                                            }
```